# Perl: if else condition getting stuck on elsif

Tags: perl, if-statement

I am reading a file which has data like this

```
a  be  cd  d
e  fe  g   h 
ae be  cd  d
q  wj  e   r
```

My code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open(tempp1,"<$temp1") or die "Could not open file $temp1: $!";
 
while(my $line=<tempp1>) {
  my @rw = split " ",$line;

   if ($rw[0] eq "e" and $rw[1] =~ /^f*/ ) 
    {print ...}

   elsif ($rw[0] eq "a" and $rw[1] =~ /^b*/ and $rw[2] =~ /^c*/ ) 
    {print ...}

   elsif ($rw[0] eq "ae" and $rw[1] =~ /^b*/ and $rw[2] =~ /^c*/ ) 
    {print ...}
}
close tempp1;
```

Now if I run then it only prints for only 1st and 3rd conditions  `($rw[0] eq "e" and $rw[1] eq "f" )`  and `($rw[0] eq "ae" and $rw[1] =~ /^b*/ and $rw[2] =~ /^c*/ )`  skipping the 2nd one but when I remove the 3rd condition the it is checking the 2nd condition and printing for it. What's the problem?

Comment: Note that  `/^f*/` matches the empty string. Did you mean `/^f/` ?

Comment: @Hakon Hagland, Yes

Comment: When I run this it prints first for second, then for first, and then for third, so it is not skipping the second one

Comment: [_reposted comment to fix a blunder_]   When you post a complete program make sure that it actually runs and does what you want. Problems: (1) With that `use strict;` the program _cannot run_ with undeclared `$temp1`. It's indeed good to have `strict` (and `warnings`) but make your sample respect it (2) As @Håkon brought up, `/^f*/` matches an empty string as well -- correct that as you clarified it. (3) Why not put something simple in those `print`s once you are presenting a supposedly complete program? Make it so people can just copy-paste and run, so it's easier for them to help you ...

Comment: ... So the question doesn't actually show the problem you report, as Dave shows in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64528866/4653379) -- and since the program isn't correct it leaves it unclear where the problem may be. When you post code that correctly shows the problem then we are all on the same page. I mean these comments only to be constructive, to help with future posts -- not as criticism :)

Comment: Normally at this point I'd suggest that you fix the question -- but now there has been an asnwer posted so changing the question could invalidate that answer and that wouldn't be nice to the person who spent time writing it. So now I'd suggest that you _add_ (content or corrections) to the question, so that people can help you out better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version of your program that I've used to test this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while(my $line=<DATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  my @rw = split " ",$line;

   if ($rw[0] eq "e" and $rw[1] =~ /^f*/ )
    {print "1 - $line\n"; }

   elsif ($rw[0] eq "a" and $rw[1] =~ /^b*/ and $rw[2] =~ /^c*/ )
    {print "2 - $line\n"; }

   elsif ($rw[0] eq "ae" and $rw[1] =~ /^b*/ and $rw[2] =~ /^c*/ )
    {print "3 - $line\n"; }
}

__DATA__
a  be  cd  d
e  fe  g   h
ae be  cd  d
q  wj  e   r
```

The output I get is this:

```
2 - a  be  cd  d
1 - e  fe  g   h
3 - ae be  cd  d
```

The first line matches condition 2. So whatever problem you're having, it would seem to be with your environment, not your code.